# Apollo Client (React) - Update cache of paginated/sorted data

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

My app contains a list of items which are retrieved from a GraphQL query. The query contains pagination (page size and page number) and sorting (ascending or descending, and a field). In the cache this leads to something like:

```
items({"pagingAndSorting": {"pageSize": 50, "pageNumber": 1, "sorting": { "direction": "asc", "field": "name"}}})
```

which contains a `data` field with the resulting data.

The issue comes when adding a new item. Our UI uses a modal to add new items, with the list visible in the background. In some cases adding a new item won't result in any change in the UI, because the new item isn't included in the current pagination/sorting. But in some cases the new item should show in the list behind the modal.

Ex - I'm viewing page 1, sorted by name, and add an item with a name of 'A' - which should show at the top of the list. In this case I would expect to see the new item appear in the list.

I've explored a few options here:

- Adding a new object to the cache - this **does not work** as the item is not part of the `items` in the paginated/sorted cache
- Refetching the query - this requires knowing the current pagination and sorting settings, or current query, so the current view can be refreshed  - which is possible
- Updating the paginated/sorted query cache - which again requires knowing a few parameters so the correct query cache can be updated. Have not tried this but it seems it would work, with quite a bit of work.

Are there other options here? Am I missing an obvious solution to adding new items to the cache to update the current List view?

Comment: I am in the exact same situation, what solution did you go with and do you care to share?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation currently, and I'm afraid there aren't any good solution to this.

If **the frontend is aware of the sorting criteria** I guess you could use that to compare your new item to the first and last in the current list. If the sorting criteria is `name/asc` and your first item has `name: Adam`, the last item `name: Celine` and your new item `name: Billie`, then you know you can push it into the list, then sort alphabetically again.

If **the frontend is NOT aware of the sorting criteria**, or it simply is too much of a hassle finding out whether it fits in the list or not: Maybe consider **solving it with UI**, adding a new section altogether above the list that says *Recently added items* or similar. This does not solve the problem of updating the cache however...